# how to using just one model for some tables?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mass-assignment

I have a website that users can send their product *(like car, mobile, computers)* and sell it online on my website, maybe something like Ebay and Amazon.

I have **ads** table that store all public information about one thing using **`Mass Assignment`**, and other categories like Mobile, Car and Computers **have their own table** and will store professional and additional information of that category on it *(for example Cars have some additional information like color, fuel type, guaranty, accidents,insurance)*.

Now as you know I have two tables (**ads** and **ads_mobile**), and for all forms I have a controller that is **`adsController`** and **`ads`** model, form will create dynamically and each form has its own inputs (For Example:Mobile and car has different inputs and fields), and I just send all dynamic forms to `adsController@check` and then I check what kind of form it is (is that Mobile? is that Car?) and then I want to send this data to model:

```
//adsController(This is just Example);
 class User extends Eloquent {

protected $fillable_ads = array('field_one', 'field_two', 'field_three');

//And I want to use fillable_mobile_ads too
protected $fillable_mobile_ads = array('field_one', 'field_two', 'field_three');

}
```

Is this possible?

How should be model and controller?

any suggestion for the structure of my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your design description, I'd look into a polymorphic relationship. This is useful for when you have multiple models (Mobile, Car, Computer) that share a specific set of information (ads) that is common to all models.

```
class Ad extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('ad_field_one', 'ad_field_two');

    public function adable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Mobile extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('mobile_field_one', 'mobile_field_two');

    public function ad() {
        return $this->morphOne('Ad', 'adable');
    }
}

class Car extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('car_field_one', 'car_field_two');

    public function ad() {
        return $this->morphOne('Ad', 'adable');
    }
}

class Computer extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('computer_field_one', 'computer_field_two');

    public function ad() {
        return $this->morphOne('Ad', 'adable');
    }
}
```

To support the above relationships, you would need to add two fields to your `ads` table: `adable_type` and `adable_id`. This can be done in a migration using the statement `$table->morphs('adable');`

Documentation on polymorphic relationships can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations).

Comment: can you please change your code to real code? i don't know what is morphOne

Comment: @LASH That is real code. `morphOne` is a one-to-one polymorphic relationship, `morphMany` is a one-to-many polymorphic relationship.

Comment: Thank you. How should be the controller? how to use more than one model in one controller? What should the name of model be?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel always uses *one* model for *one* table.
I suggest to re-think your database design. Why don't you create one table for ads and put *all* ads in there (like mobile, car and computers all in one table) and add a column which specifies which type that is:

```
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| ID | type     | field_one | field_two | field_three |
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 1  | Mobile   | {data}    | {data}    | null        |
| 2  | Mobile   | {data}    | {data}    | null        |
| 3  | Car      | null      | null      | {data}      |
| 4  | Mobile   | {data}    | {data}    | null        |
| 5  | Computer | {data}    | {data}    | {data}      |
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

In this example you have 3 mobiles, 1 car and 1 computer in *one* table. Now lets say `mobile` only uses field one and two, `car` uses field three and `computer` uses all fields.

Now from your `car` form you submit a hidden field `type=car` and field 3 only. From your `mobile` form you submit a hidden field `type=mobile` and fields 1 and 2. And so on. The non submitted fields remain `null`.

I see no need for more than one table.

Comment: This design pattern is known as single table inheritance. While it has its place, it is a bit of a red flag when you start having extra fields that are specific to individual types.

Comment: No this database design is not working! I have more than 30 different categories and if I do this I will have about 100 fields!